# BIGINT changed to exponential

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a sqlite table - addresses as below:

```
+-----------------------------+
|   appid   |   BIGINT (20)   |
|  address  |   CHAR(300)     |
|   addr_id |   BIGINT(11)    |
+-----------------------------+
```

However, when I try to save data in appid with very large number, I get something like `9.0916073007e+18`. I tried using `real` but that did not work either.

How should I fix this issue?

EDIT:

```
$qry = "select * from addresses WHERE id  = 18";
$result = $db->query($qry);
while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
     var_dump($row['appid']);  // float(9.0916073007e+18)
}
```

Comment: The "I get something like" -- where do you get that?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a problem with your presentation layer, and not directly with SQLite.  It seems that SQLite is in fact retaining the precision which it should for the `BIGINT` type.

Comment: While I insert the values like this `9091607300700000036`. When I select I get this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Did not get you!

Comment: No...tell us what you to do see this value.  Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite supports signed 64-bit integers, i.e., values up to 9223372036854775807:

```
sqlite> create table t(x);
sqlite> insert into t values(9223372036854775807);
sqlite> select * from t;
9223372036854775807
```

However, the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) says:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18, except on Windows prior to PHP 7, where it was always 32 bit.
>   […]
>   If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead.

So you have to upgrade to a recent enough 64-bit version of PHP. Or handle the values as strings.